# Inserting data in empty Sharded database in mongo when balancer is not enabled result all data in one shard

Tags: mongodb, sharding

We have to 2 mongo db shard servers(3 Replica Set each).

We created Sharded collection and inserted 200k documents. Balancer was disabled in that window and we enabled it after first test and started insert again.

While in first test all data was inserted in one shard and we got lots of  warning in mongolog:-

**splitChunk cannot find chunk [{ articleId: MinKey, sessionId: MinKey },{ articleId: "59830791", sessionId: "fb0ccc50-3d6a-4fc9-aa66-e0ccf87306ea" }) to split, the chunk boundaries may be stale**

Reason mentioned in log is possible low cardinality shard key

After second and third test when balancer was on data was balanced on both shards.

We did one more test and stopped balancer again in this test, data was going in both shards even balancer was off (pageIds were reader ids which are repeated from old tests along with some new ids for both)

Could you please tell how this mechanism is working as data should go in both shards no matter balancer is ON or OFF when key's cardinality is good.

Shard Key is :- (pageid) and (unique readerid)

Below are the insertion stats:-

1. Page read in duration 200k
2. Unique page IDs 2000

Unqiue session reading pages in duration :-  70000

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you enable sharding for a database, a primary shard will get assigned for each database.
If you insert data with balancer as disabled, all the data will go into the primary shard. Mongo Split will calculate the split point as your data grows and chunks will get created.

- Since your balancer is disabled, all the chunks will remain on same shard.
- If your balancer is in enabled state then it will balance those chunks between the shards which will result in better data distribution.

> We did one more test and stopped balancer again in this test, data was going 
>   in both shards even balancer was off (pageIds were reader ids which are 
>   repeated from old tests along with some new ids for both)

The data is already distributed in chunks and these chunks are well distributed between 2 shards. If the range of your shard key is also distributed evenly among the chunks then any new document will go in respective chunk which will lead into even data distribution.